# How can I add a Prefix value to my ds4208 barcode scanner

Tags: barcode-scanner, motorola

I have a Motorola DS4208 barcode scanner that I have been using in combination with a program. The problem is I want to prefix the scans with some character so that the program knows an item was scanned by the scanner. I've tried following the user guide's instructions but instead of prefixing a character, the scanner prefixed a carriage return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you referring to the scanner product reference guide, you should be able to scan a series of barcodes to configure the scanner with a prefix as detailed on page 4-35 of this guide: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/barcode-scanners/ds4208-product-reference-guide-en-us.pdf

Comment: Yes thats's the manual I was referencing, I can't figure out how to get the character I want as the prefix though.
Would I just write the 4 digit ASCII in barcode 39 or do I need some other value?

Comment: I don't have a device to test with but my understanding is first scan the 04h barcode on page 4-36, then 07h on page 4-35, then from Appendix D, scan the 4 barcodes representing the 4 digits of the 'ASCII value' column found in Appendix E.  So, if you want to prefix with A you would scan 1,0,6,5

Comment: Oh okay, that makes more sense! I was taking the ascii value given and scanning it as one barcode instead of individually.