# Java - identify the keyboard sending the keypress

Tags: java, keyboard, barcode-scanner, uniqueidentifier

**Summary**

I am trying to build a **JAVA application (not android)** that will interact with **multiple barcode scanners** and my plan was to use the `EventInput` in order to identify which keyboard (or barcode scanner) is sending the data. This would allow having **different barcodes working at the same time** to scan the elements in different operations.

**e.g**: 1 barcode operates for the inventory, 1 is operating for the sales, etc...

While I could theoretically add a prefix on the barcode scanner to identify it (e.g: barcode 0001 becomes xx-001), I would like to keep my code more generic and reusable, such that whoever uses it doesn't have to use more costly scanners which allow for the prefix function.

**Expected result**

The expected result would be to be able to recognize the MAC code, the ID, the hash or any other unique id of the keyboard on keypress.

**Attempts**

I've tried exploring the keypress event, but the closest I got was:

```
    public int uniqueIdTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        return e.getSource().hashCode();
    }
```

Which DOES return an id... but trying it with different devices (`Kinesis keyboard`, a random `regular keyboard`, `leelbox portable keyboard`, `on-screen keyboard`), I always get the same hashcode.

Comment: You can find the user manuals of many scanners by searching, so please check the contents that can be set carefully. [How can I add a Prefix value to my ds4208 barcode scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52257971/9014308) I don't think any scanner has a general/standard way to get the information you want to get. It is most realistic to set a different prefix code for each scanner purpose.

Comment: In the first place, such information will not be acquired at the time of `KeyEvent`. To get that information, you'll need to deal with the low-level interface of the device driver, which needs to be customized for each operating system, rather than the standard interface.